# How can i do print string by time while i running http_serve_forever() in python

Tags: python, http, datetime

I am tring to run the httpserver on the raspberrypi to connect and send data via cellphone. I can send the data and run other function, but now I would like to print the string at 12 every day. I've tried `sockettime` and `date_time_string`

Here is my code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import random
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class RequestHandler_httpd(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        global Request, test, data, case
        messagetosend = bytes('test', "utf")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.send_header('Content-Length', len(messagetosend))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(messagetosend)
        Request = self.requestline
        Request = Request[5: int(len(Request)-9)]
        return
    def date_time_string(self, timestamp=None):


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_address_httpd = ('192.168.66.19', 8080)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address_httpd, RequestHandler_httpd)
    print('start')
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try to set a cron schedule that will run a custom python code to display what you need (no need for a webserver in my opinion)

Comment: did you tried 
threading.Thread(target=myServer.serve_forever).start()?

Answer (score 0):

I see five options:

1.) run your web server and add on the same machine a cronjob, that accesses the required url (for example with wget)

2.) run your web server and add a cronjob on another machine

3.) don't use a web server at all, but just use a cron job

4.) Depending on the framework you're using for the web server you might add a thread programming a timer, executing the job and reprogramming the timer.

In general However I try to avoid adding threads to a web server. You have to be careful to not do things, that are not thread safe and this can be tricky depending on your framework. but for some use cases it could be a simple solution.

5.) almost the same like for, but simulating an http request to your own url, which will probably avoid any race condition, which you might encounter with 4.

Comment: tks alot, i'll try to use cron